# column selection with a function in a j-environment

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following column selection in a `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) # using 1.8.7 from r-forge
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = i <- rnorm(5), c = pnorm(i))
dt[, list(a,b)]  #ok
```

To streamline my code in certain computations with many and variable columns I want to replace `list(a,b)` with a function. Here is a first try:

```
.ab <- function()  quote(list(a, b))
dt[, eval(.ab())] #ok - same as above
```

Ideally, I would like to get rid of `eval()` from the `[.data.table` call and confine it to the definition of `.ab` while at the same time avoid passing the data table `dt` to the function `.ab`.

```
.eab <- function()  eval(quote(list(a, b)))
dt[, .eab()] 
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found
```

What's happening? How can this be fixed?

I suspect what's biting me is R's lexical scoping and the fact that the correct evaluation of `list(a,b)` relies on it being within the *J* environment of the data table `dt`. Alas, I don't know how to fetch a reference to the correct environment and use it as an `envir` or `enclos` argument in `dt`.

```
# .eab <- function()  eval(quote(list(a, b)), envir = ?, enclos = ?)
```

**EDIT**

This approach *almost* works:

```
.eab <- function(e)  eval(quote(list(a, b)), envir = e)
dt[, .eab(dt)]
```

There are two shortcomings: (1) column names are not returned, (2) `dt` has to be passed explicitly (which i'd rather avoid). I would also rather avoid hardcoding `dt` as the choice environment. These consideration lead an alternative way of asking the above question: is there a programmatic way to get the environment `dt` from within `.eab`?

Comment: Did you try to use `get`, which allows to retrieve an object from a specified environment ?

Comment: @juba, possibly the main part of the problem is that i do not know how to get to the environment where 'b' lives. I expect that when `.eab` is evaluated properly, `[.data.table` will worry about finding `b` and the other columns.

Comment: Why must it be a function?  The idea is to eval an expression, not a function call.  Like in the FAQ.

Comment: I have the same question as Matthew. Also, note that the code in your edit isn't really doing what you probably hope that it is. Compare the output of `dt[1, .eab(dt)]` and `dt[1, list(a,b)]` to see what I mean.

Comment: Also, to see why this is probably a wild-goose chase, examine the code of `data.table:::"[.data.table"`, particularly the code surrounding this line: `if (identical(jsubl[[1L]], quote(eval))) {`, which supplies special direction for handling j arguments that are wrapped in a call to `eval()`.

Comment: @matthew: I use functions to construct expression to be evaluated. To streamline the code a bit further I'd like not to have to explicitly 'eval'. Moreover I am trying to better understand scoping...

Comment: @Ryogi  But the `eval` remind the reader that the expression is being `eval`'d in a static environment (which is one reason grouping is fast).  `eval(e)` is only a little longer than `f()`.  Otherwise I can't think what's wrong with writing `eval`?

Comment: @josh: thanks, I didn't realize that handling of 'eval' needed to be so specific.

Comment: @matthew: nothing wrong with eval at all.  I am not suggesting any change in the way datatable handles this. I somehow assumed I could wrap the eval as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning, this may be unrobust, slow, and/or subject to break if the inner machinery of `[.data.table` changes, but if for some reason there's no way around it, here's a function that seems to meet your requirements.  I could also imagine it not working if you start using other options like `by` in `[.data.table`.

```
.eab <- function() {
  foo <- quote(list(a,b))
  ans <- eval(foo, envir = parent.frame(3)$x)
  names(ans) <- vapply(as.list(foo)[-1], deparse, character(1))
  ans
}

identical(dt[, .eab()], dt[, list(a,b)])
# TRUE
```

Again, this is subverting/reducing a lot of code that exists for a good reason.

Comment: Yep, that works. And yes, it breaks `by`, and doesn't play nice with `i` subsetting.

Answer (score 5):

The intention is to create an expression rather than a function.

```
DT[, list(a,b), by=...]  # ok

.ab = quote(list(a, b))    # simpler here, no need for function()

DT[, eval(.ab), by=...]  # same
```

This approach is one reason grouping is fast in data.table: `j` is evaluated in a static environment for all groups so the (small) overhead of each function call can be avoided.

But if `.ab` really needs to be a function for some reason, then we can certainly give it further thought.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the design choice. Together with Josh's snippet that clarifies how the `eval` code is handled it makes clear why my expectation wasn't reasonable. I do not have a compelling reason for `.ab` to be a function. I'll accept `57's answer as it manages to get what i wanted although it is hardly recommendable.